# YAML: from string to multi-line?

Tags: yaml

I have a yaml which looks like this.

Is there a way to get the "Corefile" value to multi-line?

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: ".:53 {\n    rewrite name regex (.*)\\.test\\.io {1}.default.svc.cluster.local \n    errors\n    health {\n       lameduck 5s\n    }\n    ready\n    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {\n       pods insecure\n       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa\n       ttl 30\n    }\n    prometheus :9153\n    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {\n       max_concurrent 1000\n    }\n    cache 30\n    loop\n    reload\n    loadbalance\n}\n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-25T12:36:15Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "14874"
  uid: dc352ab8-1e43-4663-8c6a-0d404f4bb4f3
```

I tried `yq -P`, but this did not help

Comment: Are you asking for a) how to manually rewrite it to be multi-line, or b) for code that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic command is this (`e` can be omitted in newer versions):

```
yq e '.data.Corefile style="literal"' test.yaml
```

However this will not work in your case, since YAML says that trailing whitespace is ignored, and thus you cannot have data with trailing whitespace formatted as literal block scalar. Relevant part of your data is:

```
default.svc.cluster.local \n
                         ^
```

This space does not seem to be relevant, so you can write additional code to remove it:

```
yq e '.data.Corefile |= sub("\s*(\n)", "${1}") | .data.Corefile style="literal"' test.yaml
```

(There is a curious bug where I cannot substitute with `"\n"` directly as that will create `"\\n"` in the data for some reason, so I use the captured newline instead.)

Result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        rewrite name regex (.*)\.test\.io {1}.default.svc.cluster.local
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-25T12:36:15Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "14874"
  uid: dc352ab8-1e43-4663-8c6a-0d404f4bb4f3
```

Comment: Works fine! After removing the space before the newline pretty printing via `yq -P` worked. Thank you!

Comment: @flyx : trailing whitespace in YAML block scalars are [preserved](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#block)

Comment: @tinita Ah, with literal block scalars at least. Line folding will not preserve them in folded block scalars, but that's not what we're dealing with here. Hmm, this means that go-yaml just arbitrarily doesn't allow trailing whitespace in literal block scalars. May be worth a bug report.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but even trailing whitespace in folded block scalars will be preserved when folding, e.g. one trailing space will result in two spaces when folding :)

Comment: @tinita You're right, I assumed otherwise because I wasn't sure but expected the trailing-space blocker in go-yaml to be there for *some* reason (even if falsely applied to literal blocks). Apparently there isn't.